# jQuery UI Sortable connectWith revert icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using sortable() to move items between 2 lists and change the sort order. What I'm trying to do is add an icon next to each item that when clicked sends the item to the other list. Here's what I have so far and haven't been able to track down the method I need. The code below successfully adds the correct icon to the element (add & remove icons) but now I need to assign a click event to the icons.

```
<ul class="sortable-list" id="availableColumns">
    <li>Apple <a href="#" class="sort-icon sort-add">Add</a></li>
    <li>Orange <a href="#" class="sort-icon sort-add">Add</a></li>
    <li>Banana <a href="#" class="sort-icon sort-add">Add</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sortable-list" id="defaultColumns">
    <li>Grapefruit <a href="#" class="sort-icon sort-remove">Remove</a></li>
</ul>

$('.sortable-list').sortable({
    cancel: false,
    connectWith: '.sortable-list',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.sender && $(ui.sender).attr('id') == 'availableColumns'){
            $(ui.item).find('.sort-icon').remove().end().append(closeIcon);
        } else if (ui.sender && $(ui.sender).attr('id') == 'defaultColumns'){
            $(ui.item).find('.sort-icon').remove().end().prepend(addIcon);
        }
    }
});

$('body').on('click.sortable-remove', '.sort-remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('REMOVE - move item to #availableColumns');
});
$('body').on('click.sortable-add', '.sort-add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('ADD - move item to #defaultColumns');
});
```

====== EDIT ========

For some reason I assumed it wasn't as easy as:

```
$('#defaultColumns').find('li:first').appendTo('#availableColumns');
```

But it appears that works fine. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use this method? I couldn't find anything to manually move a sortable item to another connectWith container.

Comment: Your edited solution looks fine to me, I can't see any issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own answer, I was worried that manually moving an item in the list without notifying the plugin would have adverse affects but haven't had any issues with this solution.

```
$('#defaultColumns').find('li:first').appendTo('#availableColumns');
```